# Unable to forward logs from syslog ng server to kafka topic

Tags: ubuntu, syslog, syslog-ng

I have setup the syslog-ng server on ubuntu and collecting logs from firewall on syslog-ng server and I want to forward that logs into the kafka topic.

#### Syslog-ng installation command

```
sudo apt-get install syslog-ng-core
sudo apt-get install -y syslog-ng-mod-python
```

### Syslog-ng Version info

```
syslog-ng 3 (3.31.2)
Config version: 3.29
Installer-Version: 3.31.2
Revision: 3.31.2-1
Compile-Date: Mar 17 2021 16:37:02
Module-Directory: /usr/lib/syslog-ng/3.31
Module-Path: /usr/lib/syslog-ng/3.31
Include-Path: /usr/share/syslog-ng/include
Available-Modules: tags-parser,sdjournal,basicfuncs,affile,pacctformat,appmodel,mod-python,hook-commands,timestamp,dbparser,kvformat,json-plugin,linux-kmsg-format,afprog,system-source,pseudofile,cef,syslogformat,cryptofuncs,afsocket,afuser,csvparser,confgen,disk-buffer
Enable-Debug: off
Enable-GProf: off
Enable-Memtrace: off
Enable-IPv6: on
Enable-Spoof-Source: on
Enable-TCP-Wrapper: on
Enable-Linux-Caps: on
Enable-Systemd: on
```

### Syslog-ng Config File

```
options {
    create_dirs(yes);
    owner(ubuntu);
    group(ubuntu);
    perm(0640);
    dir_owner(ubuntu);
    dir_group(ubuntu);
    dir_perm(0750);
};

source s_net {
    tcp(ip(0.0.0.0) port(514));
    udp(ip(0.0.0.0) port(514));
};

destination d_host-specific {
   python(
        class("syslogng_kafka.kafkadriver.KafkaDestination")
            on-error("fallback-to-string")
            options(
                hosts "localhost:9092"
                topic "syslog-events"
            )
    ); 
};

log {
    source(s_net);
    destination(d_host-specific);
};
```

But when I'm trying to restart syslog-ng server. It's throwing error like this.

```
Jul 26 18:10:51 ubuntu systemd[1]: Stopped System Logger Daemon.
Jul 26 18:10:51 ubuntu systemd[1]: Starting System Logger Daemon...
Jul 26 18:10:51 ubuntu syslog-ng[2365]: Default broker version fallback 0.9.0.1 will be applied here.
Jul 26 18:10:51 ubuntu systemd[1]: Started System Logger Daemon.
Jul 26 18:10:51 ubuntu syslog-ng[2365]: Your version of syslog-ng is not supported. Please use syslog-ng 3.7.x
Jul 26 18:10:52 ubuntu syslog-ng[2365]: Your version of syslog-ng is not supported. Please use syslog-ng 3.7.x
Jul 26 18:10:53 ubuntu syslog-ng[2365]: Your version of syslog-ng is not supported. Please use syslog-ng 3.7.x
Jul 26 18:10:53 ubuntu syslog-ng[2365]: Your version of syslog-ng is not supported. Please use syslog-ng 3.7.x
Jul 26 18:10:54 ubuntu syslog-ng[2365]: Your version of syslog-ng is not supported. Please use syslog-ng 3.7.x
Jul 26 18:10:55 ubuntu syslog-ng[2365]: Your version of syslog-ng is not supported. Please use syslog-ng 3.7.x
Jul 26 18:10:55 ubuntu syslog-ng[2365]: Your version of syslog-ng is not supported. Please use syslog-ng 3.7.x
Jul 26 18:10:56 ubuntu syslog-ng[2365]: Your version of syslog-ng is not supported. Please use syslog-ng 3.7.x
Jul 26 18:10:57 ubuntu syslog-ng[2365]: Your version of syslog-ng is not supported. Please use syslog-ng 3.7.x
Jul 26 18:10:57 ubuntu syslog-ng[2365]: Your version of syslog-ng is not supported. Please use syslog-ng 3.7.x
Jul 26 18:10:58 ubuntu syslog-ng[2365]: Your version of syslog-ng is not supported. Please use syslog-ng 3.7.x
Jul 26 18:10:59 ubuntu syslog-ng[2365]: Your version of syslog-ng is not supported. Please use syslog-ng 3.7.x
Jul 26 18:10:59 ubuntu syslog-ng[2365]: Your version of syslog-ng is not supported. Please use syslog-ng 3.7.x
Jul 26 18:11:00 ubuntu syslog-ng[2365]: Your version of syslog-ng is not supported. Please use syslog-ng 3.7.x
Jul 26 18:11:01 ubuntu syslog-ng[2365]: Your version of syslog-ng is not supported. Please use syslog-ng 3.7.x
Jul 26 18:11:01 ubuntu syslog-ng[2365]: Your version of syslog-ng is not supported. Please use syslog-ng 3.7.x
Jul 26 18:11:02 ubuntu syslog-ng[2365]: Your version of syslog-ng is not supported. Please use syslog-ng 3.7.x
Jul 26 18:11:03 ubuntu syslog-ng[2365]: Your version of syslog-ng is not supported. Please use syslog-ng 3.7.x
Jul 26 18:11:03 ubuntu syslog-ng[2365]: Your version of syslog-ng is not supported. Please use syslog-ng 3.7.x
Jul 26 18:11:04 ubuntu syslog-ng[2365]: Your version of syslog-ng is not supported. Please use syslog-ng 3.7.x
Jul 26 18:11:05 ubuntu syslog-ng[2365]: Your version of syslog-ng is not supported. Please use syslog-ng 3.7.x
Jul 26 18:11:05 ubuntu syslog-ng[2365]: Your version of syslog-ng is not supported. Please use syslog-ng 3.7.x
Jul 26 18:11:06 ubuntu syslog-ng[2365]: Your version of syslog-ng is not supported. Please use syslog-ng 3.7.x
Jul 26 18:11:07 ubuntu syslog-ng[2365]: Your version of syslog-ng is not supported. Please use syslog-ng 3.7.x
Jul 26 18:11:07 ubuntu syslog-ng[2365]: Your version of syslog-ng is not supported. Please use syslog-ng 3.7.x
Jul 26 18:11:08 ubuntu syslog-ng[2365]: Your version of syslog-ng is not supported. Please use syslog-ng 3.7.x
```

I have also tried to install latest syslog-ng server, but it's throwing error

```
syslog-ng: error while loading shared libraries: libsyslog-ng-3.33.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Please anyone can help me to figure out the issue.